# App launched with custom URL scheme. How do I return data to the calling app when done?

Tags: ios

I am taking an Android programming course at my University only I have been allowed by the teacher to do IOS but I have to implement the same projects. This project is to have two apps. The first app is a color picker from a previous assignment. The second app is to call the colorpicker and allow the user to choose a color and when done return it too the second app to be displayed.

I have defined a custom URL scheme in my ColorPicker which works fine. In my second app I have a changeColor button that has the following IBAction method.

```
- (IBAction)colorChangePressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIApplication *test = [ UIApplication sharedApplication ];    
    BOOL found =
    [ test openURL:[ NSURL URLWithString:@"colorPicker://" ] ];

    if (found) NSLog( @"Resource was found" );

    else NSLog(@"unable to locate resource" );
}
```

This indeed launches the color picker app and it behaves as expected. My question is, after the color has been selected how do I return to the calling app with the selected color? I will add a finished button in my colorPicker to be clicked when the user is done selecting the color and I will capture the values I need but I can't figure out how to get this data back to the calling app. Is there some protocol/delegate pattern I need to implement?

The complete code is on git hub at. https://github.com/jnels124/CS390H

Thanks in advance for any insight as to how to solve my problem.

Comment: Forgot to mention, if you are pulling the project from git hub and you are trying to open MyColorPicker, be sure to open the .xcworkspace not .xcproject. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I defined a custom scheme in the other project as stated in the first answer but I was unsure how to generate the query string in the called URL and return it to the calling application to be parsed. I had this resolved in the following post.

[Syntax for passing NSArray to other application with custom URL Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322813/syntax-for-passing-nsarray-to-other-application-with-custom-url-scheme)

Answer (score 2):

You need to have both apps with unique schemes. Encode the scheme of `app1` and use it as a part of `app1->app2` URL. When `app2` is finished, you'll have a `app2->app1` URL, use itto open `app1` and send it required information (encoded).

It is similar as if you've put a String extra to `app2` Intent with the name of `app1` Intent, but instead of Intent you use URL and parse it as needed.

Comment: Will try when I get back from dinner. Thanks for the response.