# Syntax for passing NSArray to other application with custom URL Scheme

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is pretty much a proof of concept app. I am trying to simply pass an NSArray of values when I launch the other app using:

```
UIApplication *test = [ UIApplication sharedApplication ];
BOOL found =
[ test openURL:[ NSURL URLWithString:@"myCalculator://data" ] ];
```

I want to replace "data" with an NSArray containing three integers. In myCalculator I implemented these methods in the delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation     {

    NSLog(@"Open application called in calculator");
    return [ self application:application handleOpenURL:url ] ;
}

// Depracted
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
     handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSLog(@"%@",application.debugDescription);
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Which indeed are called as I open the URL from the other app. So, I have to questions. How do I encode the NSArray and pass it in as I open the custom URL? And, how do I decode it in the above appDelegate methods?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I can not find anything in the documentation that talks about how to encode an NSArray to be passed into a custom URL Scheme nor decoding it on the receiving end.

Also, I am a beginner so the more details the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to build a query string:

```
NSMutableString *query = [NSMutableString string];
for (id val in myArray) {
    if (query.length) {
        [query appendString:@"&"];
    [query appendFormat:@"v=%@", val];
}

NSString *urlStr = [@"myCalculator://data?" stringByAppendingString:query];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
```

The URL will look like:

> myCalculator://data?v=1&v=2&v=3

where 1, 2, 3 will be the actual values in the array.

In the `handleOpenURL` method you need to parse this URL to get the values.

```
NSString *query = [url query];
NSArray *parts = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *part in parts) {
    NSRange equal = [part rangeOfString:@"="];
    NSString *value = [part substringFromIndex:equal.location + equal.length];
    [values addObject:value]; // If you want the value as a string
    [values addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[value intValue]]]; // If you want the value as a number
}
```

Now the `values` array has your values passed from the other app.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your Array to a string, then do the reverse on the other app.

```
     NSString *Array2String = [myArray componentsJoinedByString:@"|"];
     NSArray *String2Array = [Array2String componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
```

Of course you need to be carefully to select a string that will be used as marker that you won't be using in your existing Array (if it contains string values)

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I was thinking for sending the data, but I am unsure of the syntax for pulling it out of the URL on the receiving end. Which part of the URL object should I request to parse? I am new to using URL's and objective-c.

Comment: Probably if you want to use this approach you should settle on JSON syntax, and then standard APIs can be used to convert to/from the string form.  (In the general case you do, of course, need to escape the JSON properly for URL use, but you'd have to do that with anything.)